# Unable to drop primary key in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am unable to drop the primary key when I am trying the below command and the error is coming as shown as below:

```
mysql> alter table uoilookup drop primary key;
```

> ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of
>   '.\mysql_subr_light1_9#sql-74c_f10' to
>   '.\mysql_subr_light1_9\uoilookup' (errno: 150)

Comment: Is the PK referenced by a foreign key in some other table?

Comment: Yes Primary key is referenced in another table as foreign key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the primary key is referenced by one or more foreign keys in other tables, than you need to drop those before you can drop the primary key.

The database is doing this to ensure your data integrity, if you are using InnoDB and want to check exactly what went wrong, you can use the query `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, which you can read about in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-engine.html).

Comment: You're welcome :) if my answer was useful to you, fell free to upvote and/or accept it!

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE user_table MODIFY id INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE user_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: So this figured it out for me - I had a PK with two columns - running the modify not null on one of them exposed an FK that was related to it so I could use the PK drop.